# Switch service running state using powershell (using UAC prompts)

Tags: powershell, service, credentials

```
$serviceName = "wsearch"
$isRunning = Get-Service | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq "Running" -and $_.Name -eq $serviceName}
$isStopped = Get-Service | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq "Stopped" -and $_.Name -eq $serviceName}

if ($isStopped) {
   Start-Service -InputObject $isStopped
   Start-Sleep -s 10
}

if ($isRunning) {
   Stop-Service -InputObject $isRunning
   Start-Sleep -s 10
}
```

I want to run this script, but I don't want to set Administrator execution policy (which is set to max restrictive), while **regular user** policy is lax.

I want to run the script as a regular user and trigger the UAC prompt for each command (akin to `-Verb RunAs`), **however, Start-Service does not accept this parameter.**

I guess I can run a `Start-Process "sc"` but that defeats the purpose of powershell.

*The ultimate goal of the script* is to swtich the state of a **service** based on the current running state.

Comment: You can mimic the uac using a get creds box that loops till they enter their password/pin?

Comment: There is no way to run one-off commands elevated (as admin) in a non-elevated powershell session.  This would be similar to 'sudo' in Linux which just doesn't exist in the Windows world.  Instead you could use `Start-Process -Verb RunAs -FilePath 'powershell' -Arguments '-Command <your commands or script>'` like you mentioned to start a powershell session as administrator and run the commands so you are not limited to calling 'sc'

Comment: @Daniel but I am able to run PS scripts such as chaging fields in LDSP, So what could be done to wrape this script into a Start-Process?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala Great! But can you give an example, please sir?

Comment: dont forget to upvote the question if you gave an answer (even in the comments) I do that.

Comment: @Daniel oh your answer was pretty thoruough nevermind. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to run one-off commands elevated (as admin) in a non-elevated powershell session. This would be similar to 'sudo' in Linux which just doesn't exist in the Windows world. Instead you could use something like the following to start a powershell session as administrator and run the commands there.  You are not limited to calling 'sc'

```
Start-Process -Verb RunAs -FilePath 'powershell' -Arguments '-Command <your commands>'
```

To run a powershell script with elevated privileges you could substitute `-Command` for `-File` (but `-Command <path to file>` will also work)

```
Start-Process -Verb RunAs -FilePath 'powershell' -Arguments '-File <path to script>'
```